# Retag request: [typing] -> [types]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

These two tags clearly cover the same topic:

- [typing](/questions/tagged/typing) (146 questions)

  > For questions related to data types. Do not use this tag for questions related to the physical act of typing on a keyboard, as such questions are almost always off-topic.
- [types](/questions/tagged/types) (6,913 questions)

  > Types, and type systems, are used to enforce levels of abstraction in programs.

[typing](/questions/tagged/typing) should be retagged to [types](/questions/tagged/types) and there should probably be a synonym as well.

Comment: Perhaps we could start by fixing the tag wiki for [tag:types].  There's almost certainly other tags we're going to want to evaluate first, like [tag:strong-typing] and [tag:type-systems].

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah, I don't think that tag wiki is useful. There's a whole family of [strong-typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strong-typing), [weak-typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weak-typing), [dynamic-typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-typing), [static-typing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-typing), and I think it can make sense to keep those. Not sure about [type-systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-systems).